# Creating overlapping zones in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I'm trying to create multiple public zones in CloudDNS like this:

```
 - my-domain.com (for production)
 - dev.my-domain.com
 - qa.my-domain.com
```

I created a top level domain (my-domain.com) and added all the subdomain records, however I'd like to be able to manage the zones independently, is there any way to do this? Or is the solution to have a single zone that is `my-domain.com` and specify all subdomains in that zone.

Comment: Do you still have an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you add the nameservers for the subdomain to the top level domain, as follows:

(For example)

In the my-domain.com zone

```
dev.my-domain.com   NS   ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com.
                         ns-cloud-a2.googledomains.com.
                         ns-cloud-a3.googledomains.com.
                         ns-cloud-a4.googledomains.com.
```